# How to eliminate unwanted symbols from a binary stream

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, outputstream

I am reading a stream of binary data through RFCOMM socket. The data I receive I save it in a byte[]. Then convert it to a readable format using `new String(buff)`.

For an example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[64]
readableData = new String(buffer);
```

But what I receive after converting to readable format is smothing as shown below with strange characters at the end "the ones with question mark" :

```
/CSPPCtrl: -->[rx()]-> bytes count: 57
11-13 16:27:37.421 9543-10346/com.example.com.bt_11 I/CSPPCtrl: -->[rx()]->  
data in the buffer: S1,2829.22,3,4.65,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,69.2,25,1,0,0,0,0,0
11-13 16:27:37.421 9543-10346/com.example.com.bt_11 I/CSPPCtrl:
```

Please let me know what is the recommended way to eliminate these symbols?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int) with `buffer, 0, real_count_of_bytes_that_was_read`

Comment: Try new String(buffer,"utf-8")

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong `String` constructor. You should be using [`String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, Charset charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

The reason is that you only received 57 bytes, but the array is 64 bytes, so you specify an `offset` of 0 and a `length` of 57.

You should also specify the `charset`, so it's not dependent on the JVM default, since that may change.

Therefore, it should be something like:

```
readableData = new String(buffer, 0, buflen, "US-ASCII");
```